# Does anyone know any software that allows me to track my computer's bandwidth per hour?

Tags: network-monitor, internet, bandwidth

Does anyone know any software that allows me to track my computer's bandwidth **per hour**? I'm tethering my phone to my laptop and I don't want to go over the hourly usage limit or I'll violate the unlimited data plan's fair use policy.

I'm using Windows but Mac would be helpful too.

Comment: If you'd let us know on what OS it should run, and how much you'd be willing to spend on a paid solution if it came to that, there might be answers useful to you. Until then, you can check with our [already answered network-monitor questions](/search?q=[network-monitor]+answers%3A1).

Comment: I'm using Windows but Mac would be helpful too. The closest thing I see for Windows is Rokario Bandwidth Monitor but the Rokario website is down so I can't purchase the full version.

Comment: The connection is provided by your phone I guess (so the laptop uses your phone's mobile data)? If so, the best point to monitor data usage would be your phone – and you didn't say whether that is running on Symbian 40/60, Windows Mobile, BlackberryOS or whatever ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options you can use to monitor bandwidth utilization on your device(s). Depending on your router as well, this may have the capacity to monitor the traffic used per device over a period.

On Windows, [NetBalancer](https://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/) is a freemium application that can allow you to monitor traffic on your Windows device, and set some basic QoS rules:

[image: Monitor Tool]

Another free solution is also [NetWorx](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/), with the same functionality. However as stated, if you're using an Android phone for tethering, there are [data limits you can apply](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9458407?hl=en) which might help (even if you need to monitor them hourly).

For Mac, use the inbuilt [Activity Monitor](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201464#network) for network.